# Regular expression extracting between xml tags

Tags: regex

I have the following two lines in XML in which I am using a regular expression to match the numbers between the tags on Line 1 & Line 2:

```
type="PDF417">123456789</barcode><crnl/>
crnl/><xxPDF417>987654321</xxPDF417><crnl/>
```

I m looking to extract the following from

```
123456789
987654321
```

Regular expression I am using:

```
PDF417?>(.*?)</
```

I am getting the:

```
123456789
>987654321
```

any ideas on the expression I would need to drop the ">" from the second line?

Comment: Are you working in Qt?

Comment: [I cannot repro](https://regex101.com/r/DU1qqb/1) (even [if I add `"`](https://regex101.com/r/TGyyD9/1)), please post the code you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to try this:

```
PDF417.?>(.*?)<\/
------^-----
```

`.` is needed to match anything there and the next `?` makes it optional

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/4z7jdH/2)

Comment: Thank you Rizwan the . is what I was missing. was trying everything bar the .